# create and write to a text file in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm creating a small vb.net application, and I'm trying trying to write a list of results from a listview to a text file.  I've looked online and found the code to open the save file dialog and write the text file.  When I click save on the save file dialog, I receive an IOException with the message "The process cannot access the file 'C:\thethe.txt' because it is being used by another process."  The text file is created in the correct location, but is empty.  The application quits at this line "Dim fs As New FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)"  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim myStream As Stream
    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
            Dim fs As New FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
            Dim m_streamWriter As New StreamWriter(fs)
            m_streamWriter.Flush()
            'Write to the file using StreamWriter class
            m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            'write each row of the ListView out to a tab-delimited line in a file
            For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
                m_streamWriter.WriteLine(((ListView1.Items(i).Text & vbTab) + ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(0).ToString() & vbTab) + ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ToString())
            Next
            myStream.Close()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try simplifying and using a StreamWriter instead:

```
    Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

        If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName, False)
                'write each row of the ListView out to a tab-delimited line in a file 
                For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
                    sw.WriteLine(((ListView1.Items(i).Text & vbTab) + ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(0).ToString() & vbTab) + ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ToString())
                Next
            End Using
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

You've already opened a stream to the file using [`SaveFileDialog.OpenFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.openfile.aspx) - but then you're trying to open *another* stream at the same time with this line:

```
Dim fs As New FileStream(...)
```

Why not use the stream you've got? (Or don't call `OpenFile`.)

(Btw, a `Using` statement would help you to clean up your file handles even if an exception is thrown.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a running process that didn't released properly the resource. Maybe your debugger ?

[EDIT] Sorry, I misread the code sample...